# How to bypass Outlook credential prompt from external program?

Tags: c#, outlook, credentials, outlook-redemption

I started developing an external program to process e-mail messages from the stores in Outlook, and save them in our web application.

Today, I have an Outlook add-in that do this processing, but I wanted to avoid doing this in the add-in, because sometimes Outlook hangs from 1 to 2 seconds.

In the external program, I'm stuck in a situation where a dialog box is prompted, asking for the credentials of a user store, because the user didn't cached his credentials. I want to know if there is a way that I can avoid this dialog box to be shown. Right now, the code that I'm working with is presented below.

```
RDOSession session = RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();
session.Logon();

RDOStore store = null;

for (int i = 1; i < session.Stores.Count; i++)
{
    store = session.Stores[i];
    store.OnNewMail += (entryID) => { MessageBox.Show(entryID); };
}
```

Comment: If the credentials aren't cached and you don't provide a log in...how do you get access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will work fine as long as the store is cached. Public Folders stores are most likely not cached, and hence require credentials to access.

But most importantly, `NewMail` event is only fired on the primary mailbox in the profile, so you only need `RDOSession.Stores.DefaultStore`.

You can of course use `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Inbox folder of other stores, but, again, Public Folders stores do not have an Inbox folder. When looping through the stores, check the `RDOStore.StoreKind` property.